# Use rsync to only copy files that have changed

Tags: rsync, cp, timestamps

Right now I have these commands:

```
my_dir="$HOME/foo/bar";

rm -rf "$my_dir/WebstormProjects/";

rsync -r --exclude=".git" --exclude="node_modules" "$HOME/WebstormProjects/" "$my_dir/WebstormProjects/"
```

instead of removing everything in `"$my_dir/WebstormProjects/"` and then copying over, I am looking to use `rsync` such that it will only overwrite files in `"$my_dir/WebstormProjects/"` if the files in `"$HOME/WebstormProjects/"` are newer. So something like this:

```
my_dir="$HOME/foo/bar";

rsync -r --newer --exclude=".git" --exclude="node_modules" "$HOME/WebstormProjects/" "$my_dir/WebstormProjects/"
```

**is it possible to copy files only if they are newer than the destination files?**

I did some reading:
https://www.tecmint.com/sync-new-changed-modified-files-rsync-linux/

it says:

> By default, rsync only copies new or changed files from a source to
>   destination...

I assume it does this by comparing relative file paths? Files with the same path/name are considered to be the same?

Comment: Keep reading; `rsync` will compare timestamps as well as hashing the files. See https://serverfault.com/a/211083

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the rsync default behavior. It checks file size and last modification size.

If you want it to use checksums instead, use the `-c` or `--checksum` option (same effect). The man page is [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and describes the option, also of interest might be `--size-only`

Comment: Yeah checksum seems like the more accurate approach since we usually care about file contents..

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, it is more accurate. Just be aware that for large files it can get very slow (since it has to read and run a one-way hash on the *ENTIRE* file). If the size, name, and modified time of a file are all the same, the file has probably not updated. Unless you run into or really anticipate a problem with those causing issues you're probably just better off using rsync's sane defaults. Happy coding!

Comment: Ah yes, you are probably right